# delete text file during terraform destroy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, delete-file

I am trying to delete generated Ansible inventory `hosts` a file from my local machine when executing `terraform destroy`.

When I run `terraform apply` I use `provisioner "local-exec"` to create `hosts` file which is being used later by ansible playbook that is called during the deployment.

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo master ansible_host=${element((aws_instance.kubeadm-node.*.public_ip),0)} >> hosts"
  }
```

Is it possible to make sure that the `hosts` file is deleted when I am deleting all the resources with `terraform destroy`?
What is the easiest approach to delete `hosts` file when executing `terraform destroy`?

Thanks for your help, please let me know if my explanation was not clear enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Ansible inventory using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464397/create-ansible-inventory-using-terraform)

Comment: Additionally, there could be a problem with this approach if somehow a `hosts` file existed with some other contents, it could end up being an invalid ansible inventory as you are using `>>` to append the host details to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another `local-exec` provisioner and set it to be used only when `terraform destroy` is run, e.g.:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "rm -f /path/to/file"
    when    = destroy
  }
```

More information about using destroy time provisioners here [1].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#destroy-time-provisioners

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the [local_file resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) to handle the inventory file. This way we can easily manage the file as expected when `apply` or `destroy` is run.

Example:

```
resource "local_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  filename              = "./hosts"
  file_permission       = "0664"
  directory_permission  = "0755"
  content               = <<-EOT
    master ansible_host=${element((aws_instance.kubeadm-node.*.public_ip),0)}
  EOT
}
```